# Could ExecutorService prevent Spring RestController from responding to REST calls?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I am trying to figure out why my Microservice A get stuck at a POST call `restTemplate.postForEntity` whenever that request takes longer than 10-15 minutes and never proceeds further to `LOG.info`.

This happens even though it seems that all jobs have been completed in Microservice B, by first confirming all jobs have been run inside `jobService::executeJob`, and also that all of the `LOG.info` code have been reached. But then it hangs somewhere and prevents Microservice A from going further.

Since this only happens to heavy POST calls, I haven't been able to recreate this problem in the debugger.

- I use a default RestTemplate with an infinite timeout
- This works completely fine for lighter POST calls under a few minutes

**Microservice A**

```
public void doJobs(Collection<Job> jobs) {
    restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/jobs", jobs, Void.class);
    LOG.info("Jobs done");
}
```

**Microservice B**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/jobs")
public void post(@RequestBody Collection<Job> jobs) {
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = null;
    try {
        forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(3);
        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> jobs.parallelStream().forEach(jobService::executeJob)).get()
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        LOG.error("Error doing jobs", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unknown error occurred", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        LOG.info("Checking if fork join pool still active, shutting down if yes");
        if (forkJoinPool != null) {
            LOG.info("Shutting down fork join pool...");
            forkJoinPool.shutdown();
        }
    }
    LOG.info("Jobs completed, fork join pool successfully shut down");
}
```

Any idea what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Hm ... an HTTP request taking 15 minutes before returning a response is a rather uncommon use of HTTP. Might some network intermediary silently drop "idle" connections after X minutes of inactivity, causing the response to be lost in transit?

Comment: also I think that create pool for every request - is not a good idea